# Clean Remove Partial Binary of Homebrew in OSX Mojave

Tags: command-line, homebrew, macos

I interrupted Homebrew installation from the Terminal by pressing <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> because I realized I have little space left in the hard disk.

Now I want to clean the data that was incompletely written to my hard disk. What should I do?

I ran following commands in the Terminal to install:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This was interrupted. Now I keep getting message of low disc space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew conveniently has a few ways to uninstall it"

- Issue the command

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
  ```
- They also conveniently provide an [Uninstall script](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew)
  you can download that should remove the files from the aborted installation.

Either of these methods should get Homebrew uninstalled.

Comment: Ill give it a try. So it will clean any partial data written to the hard disk right? Most of the installers have a property that if they get interrupted they automatically perform the cleanup especially in Windows. I am not sure how the things are managed in OSX because when I interrupted the installation in the Terminal. The process simply stopped and no cleanup was done.

Comment: It's completely unlike windows - there's no Registry.  The script will go in and delete directories where the program is supposed to be.  If the directory isn't there, it will just generate a message that it couldn't be found and continue on.